# Why doesn’t GHC use my displayException method?

Tags: haskell

I have the following Haskell program where I customize the [`displayException`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:displayException) method for human-friendly display of an exception:

```
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

data MyException = MyException String
                 deriving (Show, Typeable)

instance Exception MyException where
  displayException (MyException e) = "oops! " ++ e

main = throw $ MyException "something's wrong"
```

But when I run it under GHC 8.6.4, I get

```
myprog.hs: MyException "something's wrong"
```

instead of the expected

```
myprog.hs: oops! something's wrong
```

Why isn’t my `displayException` method being used?

Answer (score 4):

GHC's runtime does not use `displayException` to report catched exceptions to the user.

You need to provide custom `Show` instance instead:

```
data MyException = MyException String
    deriving Typeable

instance Show MyException where
    show (MyException e) = "oops! " ++ e

instance Exception MyException
```

---

`displayException` was [added years ago](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-October/thread.html#24005) in order to have different methods for exception serialization (`show`) and reporting to the user (`displayException`).

In the mentioned discussion I found [this reply by Edward Kmett](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-October/024039.html) and it seems like a good reason for GHC RTS not to use `displayException`.

> My experience is that whenever someone writes a "helpful" Show
>   instance it winds up anything but.
>
> Why?
>
> What happens when you print a list of them, or they occur deeper in a
>   larger structure?
>
> Invariably I wind up with things like a bag of your exceptions in an
>   async exception wrapper or someone's position type in my data
>   structure [...]
>
> "Helpful" Show instances are not compositional.

So GHC RTS tires to provide the developer with as much detailed and parsable information about unhandled exceptions as possible. Leaving the ability to use `displayExceptions` to tell the end user about handled exceptions.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an example showing how to use `displayException` correctly too ?

Comment: I don't think it is used somehow extensively, but I found original [discussion](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-October/thread.html#24005) about adding it.

Comment: I found that discussion, too, and that’s what I’m wondering about: why isn’t is used for the specific purpose it was intended for?